# Scrollview on ListView Flutter

Tags: flutter-layout

### I want to add scroll view to only list, but the scrollview is scrolling the entire page.
i want to implement scrolling only for list item. kindly suggest help as i am new to flutter.
I want to add scroll view to only list, but the scrollview is scrolling the entire page.
i want to implement scrolling only for list item. kindly suggest help as i am new to flutter.I want to add scroll view to only list, but the scrollview is scrolling the entire page.
i want to implement scrolling only for list item. kindly suggest help as i am new to flutter.
[This is the screen where scrollview should start after brown header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idXzm.png)

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    pr = ProgressDialog(context);
    getData().then((serviceData) => {_serviceData = serviceData});
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.light
        .copyWith(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent));
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back_ios_new_outlined,
          ),
        ),
        title: Text("My Request"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
         child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      _selectStartDate(context);
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 15.0),
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Icon(Icons.date_range_outlined),
                              Text("Start Date",
                                  style:
                                  TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                              Text(startDate),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      _selectDate(context);
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 15.0),
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Icon(Icons.date_range_outlined),
                              Text("End Date",
                                  style:
                                  TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                              Text(getDateTime()),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                        height: 55,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                            color: Colors.brown,
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              width: 2,
                            )),
                        child: Text("Sr No.",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                        height: 55,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                            color: Colors.brown,
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              width: 2,
                            )),
                        child: Text("Date & Time",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                        height: 55,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                            color: Colors.brown,
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              width: 2,
                            )),
                        child: Text("Request",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                        height: 55,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                            color: Colors.brown,
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              width: 2,
                            )),
                        child: Text("Status",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            FutureBuilder(
                future: getData(),
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  } else {
                    return Container(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: _serviceData == null || _serviceData.isEmpty
                          ? Text(
                        "No Record Found",
                        style:
                        TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.brown),
                      )
                          : ListView.builder(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          physics: new BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                          itemCount: null == _serviceData
                              ? 0
                              : _serviceData.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            PatientServiceDetails pd = _serviceData[index];
                            return Card(
                              child: InkWell(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    showDialogFunc(context, pd);
                                  },
                                  child: Container(
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: Container(
                                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                                              child: ListTile(
                                                title: Text(
                                                    pd.requestNumber.toString(),
                                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                        fontSize: 12,
                                                        color: getColor(
                                                            pd.status))),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: Container(
                                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                                              child: ListTile(
                                                title: Text(
                                                    pd.createdDate.toString(),
                                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                        fontSize: 12)),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: Container(
                                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                                              child: ListTile(
                                                title: Text(
                                                    pd.reqComment.toString(),
                                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                        fontSize: 12)),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: Container(
                                              child: ListTile(
                                                title: Text(
                                                    getStatus(pd.status),
                                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                        fontSize: 12)),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ))),
                            );
                          }),
                    );
                  }
                }),
            // container
          ],
        ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Column` and `Listview.Builder()`

see this sample build method. you can replace the "TOP WIDGETS" with your widgts. using this build method you can achieve your expected behaviour

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body : Column(
      mainAxisSize:MainAxisSize.max,
        children:[
          Container(child: Text("TOP WIDGETS")),
          Expanded(
          flex:1,
            child:ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 50,
            itemBuilder: (context,index){
            return Text("List Item 1");
            },
          )
          )
        ]
      )
    );
  }
```

This very simple and effective way, ListView.Builder() can be used for dynamic lists and can handle if value is null!

[image: Sample img for above code]